# Python: scrape multiple pages of a message board

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

I would like to be able to scrape all the messages from message pages of Yahoo finance for a specific stock.

Here is an example page:
http://finance.yahoo.com/mb/AMD/

I like to be able to get all the messages in there.
If I click on the "Messages" button on the above link I go to this link:
http://finance.yahoo.com/mb/forumview/?&v=m&bn=d56b9fc4-b0f1-3e88-b1f5-e1c40c0067e7
which has more than 10 pages.

How can I use Python code to scrape this data by just knowing the stock symbol "AMD"?

Comment: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Comment: Jonathan: Can you please elaborate a little? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The basics:

```
tickers = ['AMD', 'AAPL', 'GOOG']
for t in tickers:
   url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/mb/' + t + '/'
   r = br.open(url)
   html = r.read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
   print soup
```

The content you want is located within particular html tags. Use `soup.find_all` to get what you want. To move between pages, use Selenium.